# Understanding KafkaConsumer seek

Tags: java, apache-kafka

The method [seek()](https://kafka.apache.org/33/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-long-) in the KafkaConsumer class has this javadoc comment:

> Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next poll(timeout). If this API is invoked for the same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the next poll(). **Note that you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily used in the middle of consumption**, to reset the fetch offsets

I wonder what is meant by "in the middle of consumption"? Does it mean I can't safely call seek in a poll loop and should I do it only *before* the first poll? Moreover, what happens when invoking seek followed by a commitAsync() or commitSync()? Will the seek position be committed?

Thanks for clarification!

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I have rephrased the main question. And what's the problem with having an additional question on the same topic?

Comment: There should be *one* question.  No one can definitively answer this until that change is made.

Comment: @possum Each of the questions are related to one another. And they can be answered together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the fact that you'd first poll up to `max.poll.records` (default 500), and then be in the middle of processing those, and regardless of committing, you will modify where the next poll will happen. Meaning, you could skip records, i.e. lose records (seek forward), or eventually cause duplicate processing (seek backward).

Ideally, you'd break any loop over the consumed records, `commitSync()` with what you have processed (or not if seeking backwards), call `consumer.pause()`, and **then** `seek`. Or yes, seek (and commit the seeked offsets) before you poll.

If you do not pause/stop the consumer, then it's possible the consumer will rebalance while seeking since `max.poll.interval.ms` could be exceeded.

Comment: Thank you! But why do I have to call `pause()`? Do you have a concurrent situation in mind with one thread doing the poll loop and another one that tries to modify the offsets using `seek()`?

Comment: KafkaConsumer is not thread safe, so you should definitely stop/pause it before trying to do anything with the offsets it'll poll on the next call, especially if [multithreading](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#multithreaded)